# Mongo returning multiple results when one query is stored as variable

Tags: mongodb

I am having two queries. One is returning array as output, which is stored into a variable. This variable is used later in another query.

**My Code:**

```js
// query stored in variable
owners = db.stores.distinct('owner', {'type': 'marketplace'})
db.stores.find({'owner': { '$in': owners }})
```

**Problem:**

I cannot figure out, why `Robo 3T` (MongoDB client) is returning two separate results. One is for the first query, which is stored into a variable, and another one for the second query.

Any ideas? What are good practices for doing queries like this?

Comment: (1) The first query returns an array of _owners_. It is the query result stored in a variable `owners`. (2) The second query returns a _cursor_, matching the filter. (3)What is the purpose of the above two queries - together or individually? See [db.collection.find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) and [db.collection.distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) about their usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found answer - Robo 3T is **NOT** returning double results if variable you are using has `var` keyword in front of declaration:

```js
var owners = db.stores.distinct('owner', {'type': 'marketplace'})
db.stores.find({'owner': { '$in': owners }})
```